# jQuery nestedSortable - how to make first item root and subsequent items children of root

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, nested-sortable

I have a form that you can generate a sortable menu structure with. I want to make the first item the parent and all subsequent items it's children. I have achieved this visually but I need to also ensure the code structure is correct.

In my options I noticed that protectRoot and rootID are not working but I don't think it's impacting on anything in the code.

jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/EazX7/

**JS**

```
// Nested Sortable Plugin
/*
 * jQuery UI Nested Sortablefdfv
* v 1.3.4 / 28 apr 2011
* http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable
*
* Depends:
*     jquery.ui.sortable.js 1.8+
*
* License CC BY-SA 3.0
* Copyright 2010-2011, Manuele J Sarfatti
*/

(function($) {

$.widget("ui.nestedSortable", $.extend({}, $.ui.sortable.prototype, {

    options: {
        tabSize: 20,
        disableNesting: 'ui-nestedSortable-no-nesting',
        errorClass: 'ui-nestedSortable-error',
        listType: 'ol',
        maxLevels: 0,
        noJumpFix: 0
    },

    _create: function(){
        if (this.noJumpFix == false)
            this.element.height(this.element.height());
        this.element.data('sortable', this.element.data('nestedSortable'));
        return $.ui.sortable.prototype._create.apply(this, arguments);
    },



    _mouseDrag: function(event) {

        //Compute the helpers position
        this.position = this._generatePosition(event);
        this.positionAbs = this._convertPositionTo("absolute");

        if (!this.lastPositionAbs) {
            this.lastPositionAbs = this.positionAbs;
        }

        //Do scrolling
        if(this.options.scroll) {
            var o = this.options, scrolled = false;
            if(this.scrollParent[0] != document && this.scrollParent[0].tagName != 'HTML') {

                if((this.overflowOffset.top + this.scrollParent[0].offsetHeight) - event.pageY < o.scrollSensitivity)
                    this.scrollParent[0].scrollTop = scrolled = this.scrollParent[0].scrollTop + o.scrollSpeed;
                else if(event.pageY - this.overflowOffset.top < o.scrollSensitivity)
                    this.scrollParent[0].scrollTop = scrolled = this.scrollParent[0].scrollTop - o.scrollSpeed;

                if((this.overflowOffset.left + this.scrollParent[0].offsetWidth) - event.pageX < o.scrollSensitivity)
                    this.scrollParent[0].scrollLeft = scrolled = this.scrollParent[0].scrollLeft + o.scrollSpeed;
                else if(event.pageX - this.overflowOffset.left < o.scrollSensitivity)
                    this.scrollParent[0].scrollLeft = scrolled = this.scrollParent[0].scrollLeft - o.scrollSpeed;

            } else {

                if(event.pageY - $(document).scrollTop() < o.scrollSensitivity)
                    scrolled = $(document).scrollTop($(document).scrollTop() - o.scrollSpeed);
                else if($(window).height() - (event.pageY - $(document).scrollTop()) < o.scrollSensitivity)
                    scrolled = $(document).scrollTop($(document).scrollTop() + o.scrollSpeed);

                if(event.pageX - $(document).scrollLeft() < o.scrollSensitivity)
                    scrolled = $(document).scrollLeft($(document).scrollLeft() - o.scrollSpeed);
                else if($(window).width() - (event.pageX - $(document).scrollLeft()) < o.scrollSensitivity)
                    scrolled = $(document).scrollLeft($(document).scrollLeft() + o.scrollSpeed);

            }

            if(scrolled !== false && $.ui.ddmanager && !o.dropBehaviour)
                $.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets(this, event);
        }

        //Regenerate the absolute position used for position checks
        this.positionAbs = this._convertPositionTo("absolute");

        //Set the helper position
        if(!this.options.axis || this.options.axis != "y") this.helper[0].style.left = this.position.left+'px';
        if(!this.options.axis || this.options.axis != "x") this.helper[0].style.top = this.position.top+'px';

        //Rearrange
        for (var i = this.items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            //Cache variables and intersection, continue if no intersection
            var item = this.items[i], itemElement = item.item[0], intersection = this._intersectsWithPointer(item);
            if (!intersection) continue;

            if(itemElement != this.currentItem[0] //cannot intersect with itself
                &&    this.placeholder[intersection == 1 ? "next" : "prev"]()[0] != itemElement //no useless actions that have been done before
                &&    !$.contains(this.placeholder[0], itemElement) //no action if the item moved is the parent of the item checked
                && (this.options.type == 'semi-dynamic' ? !$.contains(this.element[0], itemElement) : true)
                //&& itemElement.parentNode == this.placeholder[0].parentNode // only rearrange items within the same container
            ) {

                this.direction = intersection == 1 ? "down" : "up";

                if (this.options.tolerance == "pointer" || this._intersectsWithSides(item)) {
                    this._rearrange(event, item);
                } else {
                    break;
                }

                // Clear emtpy ul's/ol's
                this._clearEmpty(itemElement);

                this._trigger("change", event, this._uiHash());
                break;
            }
        }

        var parentItem = (this.placeholder[0].parentNode.parentNode && $(this.placeholder[0].parentNode.parentNode).closest('.ui-sortable').length) ? $(this.placeholder[0].parentNode.parentNode) : null;
        var level = this._getLevel(this.placeholder);
        var childLevels = this._getChildLevels(this.helper);
        var previousItem = this.placeholder[0].previousSibling ? $(this.placeholder[0].previousSibling) : null;
        if (previousItem != null) {
            while (previousItem[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'li' || previousItem[0] == this.currentItem[0]) {
                if (previousItem[0].previousSibling) {
                    previousItem = $(previousItem[0].previousSibling);
                } else {
                    previousItem = null;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        newList = document.createElement(o.listType);

        this.beyondMaxLevels = 0;

        // If the item is moved to the left, send it to its parent level
        if (parentItem != null && this.positionAbs.left < parentItem.offset().left) {
            parentItem.after(this.placeholder[0]);
            this._clearEmpty(parentItem[0]);
            this._trigger("change", event, this._uiHash());
        }
        // If the item is below another one and is moved to the right, make it a children of it
        else if (previousItem != null && this.positionAbs.left > previousItem.offset().left + o.tabSize) {
            this._isAllowed(previousItem, level+childLevels+1);
            if (!previousItem.children(o.listType).length) {
                previousItem[0].appendChild(newList);
            }
            previousItem.children(o.listType)[0].appendChild(this.placeholder[0]);
            this._trigger("change", event, this._uiHash());
        }
        else {
            this._isAllowed(parentItem, level+childLevels);
        }

        //Post events to containers
        this._contactContainers(event);

        //Interconnect with droppables
        if($.ui.ddmanager) $.ui.ddmanager.drag(this, event);

        //Call callbacks
        this._trigger('sort', event, this._uiHash());

        this.lastPositionAbs = this.positionAbs;
        return false;

    },

    _mouseStop: function(event, noPropagation) {

        // If the item is in a position not allowed, send it back
        if (this.beyondMaxLevels) {
            var parent = this.placeholder.parent().closest(this.options.items);

            for (var i = this.beyondMaxLevels - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                parent = parent.parent().closest(this.options.items);
            }

            this.placeholder.removeClass(this.options.errorClass);
            parent.after(this.placeholder);
            this._trigger("change", event, this._uiHash());
        }

        $.ui.sortable.prototype._mouseStop.apply(this, arguments);

    },

    serialize: function(o) {

        var items = this._getItemsAsjQuery(o && o.connected);
        var str = []; o = o || {};

        $(items).each(function() {
            var res = ($(o.item || this).attr(o.attribute || 'id') || '').match(o.expression || (/(.+)[-=_](.+)/));
            var pid = ($(o.item || this).parent(o.listType).parent('li').attr(o.attribute || 'id') || '').match(o.expression || (/(.+)[-=_](.+)/));
            if(res) str.push((o.key || res[1]+'['+(o.key && o.expression ? res[1] : res[2])+']')+'='+(pid ? (o.key && o.expression ? pid[1] : pid[2]) : 'root'));
        });

        if(!str.length && o.key) {
            str.push(o.key + '=');
        }

        return str.join('&');

    },

    toHierarchy: function(o) {

        o = o || {};
        var sDepth = o.startDepthCount || 0;
        var ret = [];

        $(this.element).children('li').each(function() {
            var level = _recursiveItems($(this));
            ret.push(level);
        });

        return ret;

        function _recursiveItems(li) {
            var id = ($(li).attr(o.attribute || 'id') || '').match(o.expression || (/(.+)[-=_](.+)/));
            if (id != null) {
                var item = {"id" : id[2]};
                if ($(li).children(o.listType).children('li').length > 0) {
                    item.children = [];
                    $(li).children(o.listType).children('li').each(function () {
                        var level = _recursiveItems($(this));
                        item.children.push(level);
                    });
                }
                return item;
            }
        }
    },

    toArray: function(o) {

        o = o || {};
        var sDepth = o.startDepthCount || 0;
        var ret = [];
        var left = 2;

        ret.push({"item_id": 'root', "parent_id": 'none', "depth": sDepth, "left": '1', "right": ($('li', this.element).length + 1) * 2});

        $(this.element).children('li').each(function () {
            left = _recursiveArray(this, sDepth + 1, left);
        });

        function _sortByLeft(a,b) {
            return a['left'] - b['left'];
        }
        ret = ret.sort(_sortByLeft);

        return ret;

        function _recursiveArray(item, depth, left) {

            right = left + 1;

            if ($(item).children(o.listType).children('li').length > 0) {
                depth ++;
                $(item).children(o.listType).children('li').each(function () {
                    right = _recursiveArray($(this), depth, right);
                });
                depth --;
            }

            id = ($(item).attr(o.attribute || 'id')).match(o.expression || (/(.+)[-=_](.+)/));

            if (depth === sDepth + 1) pid = 'root';
            else {
                parentItem = ($(item).parent(o.listType).parent('li').attr('id')).match(o.expression || (/(.+)[-=_](.+)/));
                pid = parentItem[2];
            }

            if (id != null) {
                    ret.push({"item_id": id[2], "parent_id": pid, "depth": depth, "left": left, "right": right});
            }

            return left = right + 1;
        }

    },

    _clear: function(event, noPropagation) {

        $.ui.sortable.prototype._clear.apply(this, arguments);

        // Clean last empty ul/ol
        for (var i = this.items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var item = this.items[i].item[0];
            this._clearEmpty(item);
        }
        return true;

    },

    _clearEmpty: function(item) {

        if (item.children[1] && item.children[1].children.length == 0) {
            item.removeChild(item.children[1]);
        }

    },

    _getLevel: function(item) {

        var level = 1;

        if (this.options.listType) {
                var list = item.closest(this.options.listType);
                while (!list.is('.ui-sortable')/* && level < this.options.maxLevels*/) {
                        level++;
                        list = list.parent().closest(this.options.listType);
                }
        }

        return level;
    },

    _getChildLevels: function(parent, depth) {
        var self = this,
            o = this.options,
            result = 0;
        depth = depth || 0;

        $(parent).children(o.listType).children(o.items).each(function (index, child) {
                result = Math.max(self._getChildLevels(child, depth + 1), result);
        });

        return depth ? result + 1 : result;
    },

    _isAllowed: function(parentItem, levels) {
        var o = this.options
        // Are we trying to nest under a no-nest or are we nesting too deep?
        if (parentItem == null || !(parentItem.hasClass(o.disableNesting))) {
            if (o.maxLevels < levels && o.maxLevels != 0) {
                this.placeholder.addClass(o.errorClass);
                this.beyondMaxLevels = levels - o.maxLevels;
            } else {
                this.placeholder.removeClass(o.errorClass);
                this.beyondMaxLevels = 0;
            }
        } else {
            this.placeholder.addClass(o.errorClass);
            if (o.maxLevels < levels && o.maxLevels != 0) {
                this.beyondMaxLevels = levels - o.maxLevels;
            } else {
                this.beyondMaxLevels = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}));

$.ui.nestedSortable.prototype.options = $.extend({}, $.ui.sortable.prototype.options, $.ui.nestedSortable.prototype.options);
})(jQuery);

// Create Div
$(".add_menu_item").live('click', function() {
var value = $(this).prev().val();
if (value.length) {
    var newDiv = $('<div id="toggleshow' + "0" + numToggle++ +'" class="div_menu_button"></div>');
    var showDiv = $('<div id="show'+ "0" + numShow++ +'" class="menu_button_info">Haywood Tjibloumi</div>');
    $('#created_buttons_list').append(
        newDiv.val(value).text(value) );
        newDiv.wrap("<li></li>");
        newDiv.append(showDiv);
}

});
    var numToggle = 0;
    var numShow = 0;


   // Nested Divs Options
    $('ol#created_buttons_list').nestedSortable({
        disableNesting: 'no-nest',
        protectRoot: true,
        rootID: '#theroot',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        handle: 'div',
        helper: 'clone',
        items: 'li:not(.dontsortme)',
        maxLevels: 10,
        opacity: .6,
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        revert: 250,
        tabSize: 25,
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        toleranceElement: '> div'
});


    // Toggle Hide/SHow
    $('#toggleshow').live('click', function() {$('#show').slideToggle('slow', function() {});});
    $('#toggleshow00').live('click', function() {$('#show00').slideToggle('slow', function() {});});
    $('#toggleshow01').live('click',function() {$('#show01').slideToggle('slow', function() {});});
    $('#toggleshow02').live('click',function() {$('#show02').slideToggle('slow', function() {});});
    $('#toggleshow03').live('click',function() {$('#show03').slideToggle('slow', function() {});});
    $('#toggleshow04').live('click',function() {$('#show04').slideToggle('slow', function() {});});
    $('#toggleshow05').live('click',function() {$('#show05').slideToggle('slow', function() {});});

// Indent first item
$("input.add_menu_item").live('click', function(){
    $("#created_buttons_list li:first").css('margin-left','0px').addClass('dontsortme');
});
```

**CSS**

```
form#create_menu_item{ width:920px; }
form#create_menu_item input#new_menu_name{ padding:5px; float:left; margin:0 10px 10px 0; }
form#create_menu_item input.add_menu_item{font-size:11px; width:60px; height:27px; display:block; -moz-border-radius:3px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; -o-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px; background:#f5f5f5; background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #eee, #fcfcfc); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fcfcfc, #eee) !important; background: -o-linear-gradient(#fcfcfc, #eee);border:1px solid #ccc;color:#666;padding-bottom:3px;float:left;}
div.div_menu_button{font-size:12px;width:295px;height:16px;display:block;-moz-border-radius:3px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; -o-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px;background:#f5f5f5; background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #eee, #fcfcfc); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fcfcfc, #eee) !important; background: -o-linear-gradient(#fcfcfc, #eee);border:1px solid #ccc;color:#666;padding:10px;margin:0 0 10px 0;}
div#created_buttons{ width:680px; border:1px solid #eee; min-height:400px; padding:10px;}
.clear{ clear:both;}
#show, #show00, #show01, #show02, #show03, #show04, #show05 { display:none;}
.ui-nestedSortable-error { background:#fbe3e4; color:#8a1f11;}
ol#created_buttons_list{ margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-left: 30px;}
ol#created_buttons_list, ol#created_buttons_list ol { margin: 0 0 0 25px; padding: 0; list-style-type: none;}
ol#created_buttons_list { margin: 10px 0 10px 0;}
#created_buttons_list li { margin: 7px 0 0 0; padding: 0;}
#created_buttons_list li div  { padding: 10px; margin: 0; cursor: move;}
.placeholder { background-color: #f9f9f9; border:1px dashed #ccc;}
#created_buttons li{margin-left: 25px; padding-left: 25px;}
```

**HTML**

```
      <div>
          <form id="create_menu_item">
            <ul class="add_remove_list">
                <li><h4>Add Menu Item</h4></li>
                <li><input id="new_menu_name" type="text" name="new_menu_name" placeholder="Please enter your menu title">
                    <input class="add_menu_item" name="add_menu_item" value="Add" type="button">
                </li>
                <li class="clear"><h4>Menu Items</h4></li>
                  <li><div id="created_buttons"> <ol id="created_buttons_list"> </ol>  </div>                        
                </li>
            </ul>
                </form> 
        </div>
```

Comment: Comments as to why this was downvoted would be useful

Answer (score 0):

[`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated in jQuery since v1.7, and has been removed in v1.9.

You should replace it with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

`.on` has 2 signatures for binding event handlers, whereas `.live` only had 1.

If the element exists at the time you are binding, you do it like this:

```
$('.element').on('click', function(){
  .......
});
```

You can even use the shorthand:

```
$('.element').click(function(){
   .........
});
```

If the element does not exist at the time, or new ones will be added (which is what `.live` was normally used for), you need to use "event delegation":

```
$(document).on('click', '.element', function(){
   ........
});
```

NOTE: You want to bind to the closest static element, not always `document`.

In the meantime, the [**jQuery Migrate plugin**](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin) can be used to restore the `.live()` functionality if you upgrade your jQuery to the newest version.

Comment: Thanks Roy, I'll review the .live function. Cheers